# Using declared variables as column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to use a dynamic variable as a column name as well - for example if I hypothetically use the following to define a financial year:

```
DECLARE @currentfy NVARCHAR(6) --Current financial year
SET @currentfy = YEAR(GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I then want to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT @currentfy AS @currentfy
SELECT @currentfy - 1 AS @currentfy_1
```

So that it looks like as if I had done this:

```
SELECT 2010 AS [2010]
SELECT 2009 AS [2009]
```

Is there a way to do this without using dynamic pivoting? (as my tables are large and I want to avoid pivoting if possible).

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but what is dynamic pivoting? Is it simply a dynamic query that uses pivoting?

Comment: WHat I was referring to was this: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx - i.e. pivoting data where the column names are not known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, use dynamic pivoting or an extra column/resultset to describe the subsequent columns/resultset